# Make an object follow the mouse pointer with LÖVE2D

Tags: mathematics, lua, love2d

I've been trying to make a picture follow the mouse pointer with LÖVE2D.

I want that the object follow the mouse, and not just **be** the mouse coordinates, I did that. So I toked the distance between the objects:

```
distance = dist(object.x, mouseX, object.y, mouseY)
```

the dist definition is the one from analytic geometry(Distance between two points in the Cartesian plan), well, now I don't know what to do, I tried a timer to update the object's coordinates but didn't work out.

```
if object.timer >= 2 then
    --object.x = mouseX
    --object.y = mouseY    
    object.x = mouseX - distance    
    object.y = mouseY - distance
    object.timer = 0
end
```

It didn't work out either :(. Well, I tried some other stuff, like whale.x - distance, but didn't worked out either, how can I make the object follow the mouse, like, if I let my mouse on (500, 300(Screen coordinates) the image would follow until it reaches the position desired which is the mouse position.

And yea, I really need to learn more math. >.>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, [vector geometry](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html) really helps when thinking about positions of things. It might be helpful to read over that page for a refresher.

To find the vector from your `object` to the mouse position, subtract the `object` position from the mouse position:

```
local objectToMouse = {
    x = mousex - object.x,
    y = mouseY - object.y
}
```

Then you can add some fraction of that vector to your `object`'s position:

```
local fraction = 1 / 10
object.x = object.x + (objectToMouse.x * fraction)
object.y = object.y + (objectToMouse.y * fraction)
```

You can put those in your `love.update` to make them happen every step. Then every step the object will move one tenth of the distance to the mouse position.

It looks like this for me if I render a circle at the `object`'s position:

[image: demo]

If you find yourself using a lot of vectors, there's a really good [vector class](http://vrld.github.io/hump/#hump.vector) in [vrld's `HUMP`](http://love2d.org/wiki/HUMP) library that might simplify your code by letting you do the common vector operations with less code.

Comment: Uow, nice explanation, I gonna try your implementation and return here to mark as correct, thank you to pointing vector geometry, I've never heard about it hahaha, but I already done this kinda of sum, subtraction in vectors.